# Does graph of a monotone function have measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, monotone-functions

I know that if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous its graph has measure zero in $\mathbb{R^2}$ but what if $f$ is just monotonic(possibly discontinuous)?

Let us denote the set of discontinuities by $D$, I was thinking on since $D$ is at most countable we have no problem there but I do not know what $[a,b]\setminus D$ looks like. I am not sure if the graph necessarily has measure zero in this case.

Comment: Graph of any measurable function $E \to \mathbb{R}$ on a measureable set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In the case of $E=[a,b]$, let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and note that $$\text{[graph of $f$]}\subseteq\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\{x\in[a,b]:k\epsilon \leq f(x)<(k+1)\epsilon\}\times[k\epsilon,(k+1)\epsilon) $$ and note that the set in the right-hand side has measure $\epsilon (b - a)$. So letting $\epsilon \to 0^+$ proves the desired result.

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks